# Problem with dictionary (auto-complete field in database)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, dictionary

I have the following code in which I create a customer. Next, with the help of dictionary, for each entered email I want to create my Id_Cus

```
public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
            customer cust = new customer();
            {
                //cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
                //}
                Dictionary<string, int> dict = dc.customers.GroupBy(x => x.Email_Cus, y => y.Id_Cus)
                                                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

                dc.customers.Add(cust);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                int k = Convert.ToInt32(cust.Id_Cus);
                customer custFromDb = (from n in dc.customers
                                       where n.Id_Cus == k
                                       select n).Include(c => c.customerpreference).Include(c=>c.orders).Include(c=>c.dishesrankings).First();
            }

        }
```

I tried to start recording in this way, however, after recording the first customer with Id_Cus= 0, an exception is thrown
"MySqlException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'customer.PRIMARY'"

What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: I added auto incremental in the database. This solved the problem. But a new one has arisen: Now the following happens: if I add customer it assigns id = 1 to it, create the second one id = 2, then delete the second one, in theory the next one should be added with id = 2, but added with id = 3, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your theory is wrong, that's all. And there is no problem. New items get new numbers, and there is no idea of looking for unsused id-numbers. You want the items having the same id- just because they don't exist in the same time ? That's dangerous to mixup. You should not care for the id in general. They have to be unique and different.